# Solve PDE with condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \sqrt{x}u_x - \sqrt{y}u_y = u^2 \\
        u_{x=y} = \phi (y)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I want to change u(x,y) to v$(\tau, s )$ :
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{dx}{ds} = \sqrt{x} , x(s=0) = \tau \implies x = (\frac{s+c}{2})^2\tau^2 \\
        \frac{dy}{ds} = -\sqrt{y} , y(s=0) = \tau \implies y = (\frac{-s+c}{2})^2\tau^2 \\
        \tau = \frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{c} \\
        s^2 = 2\frac{x+y}{\tau^2} - c^2 = 2\frac{c^2(x+y)}{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2} - c^2 = (c\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}})^2 \\
        s = c\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
So we change the condition to :
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{dv}{ds} = v^2 \\
        v_{s=0} = \phi(\tau^2) \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
We find the solution :
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        v = \frac{-1}{s+c} \\
        v_{s=0} = \phi(\tau^2) \\
        \implies v = \frac{-\phi(\tau^2)}{s\phi(\tau^2)+c} \\
        Check : \frac{dv}{ds} = \frac{\phi^2(\tau^2)}{(s\phi(\tau^2)+c)^2} = v^2 \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Change $v(\tau, s)$ to $u(x,y)$ :
\begin{equation}
    u(x,y) = \frac{-\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2})}{c\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) + c} = \frac{-\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2})}{\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) + 1} \\ 
\end{equation}
Choose simple case c = 1
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{du}{dx} = -\frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})sgn(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) - |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|}{2\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2(\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) + 1)^2}\phi^2(\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) \\ 
        \frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{-(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})sgn(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) - |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|}{2\sqrt{y}(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2(\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) + 1)^2}\phi^2(\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) \\
        \sqrt{x}\frac{du}{dx} - \sqrt{y}\frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{sgn(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) }{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})(\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}\phi( \frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) + 1)^2}\phi^2(\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{c^2}) \neq u^2
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where did i do wrong ?

Comment: Please clarify your notation $u_{x=y} = \phi (y)$. Does it mean $u(y,y)=\phi(y)$ or $\frac{\partial u(y,y)}{\partial y}=\phi(y)$ or something else ?

Comment: Why not the method of characteristics giving very easily the general solution $$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{-2\:\sqrt{x}+F(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}$$ Where $F$ is an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll present a solution similar to yours, then you can compare them to find your mistakes.

The equations for the characteristic curves are given by
$$
\frac{dx}{ds}=\sqrt{x},\qquad \frac{dy}{ds}=-\sqrt{y}, \qquad
\frac{du}{ds}=u^2. \tag{1}
$$
Solving them, we find
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x}&=\sqrt{x_0}+\frac{s}{2}, \tag{2a} \\
\sqrt{y}&=\sqrt{y_0}-\frac{s}{2}, \tag{2b} \\
u&=\frac{u_0}{1-u_0s}. \tag{2c}
\end{align}
The condition $u(y,y)=\phi(y)$ is equivalent to
$$
x(0)=x_0=y_0, \qquad y(0)=y_0, \qquad
u(0)=u_0=\phi(y_0), \tag{3}
$$
so Eqs. $(2)$ can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x}&=\sqrt{y_0}+\frac{s}{2}, \tag{4a} \\
\sqrt{y}&=\sqrt{y_0}-\frac{s}{2}, \tag{4b} \\
u&=\frac{\phi(y_0)}{1-\phi(y_0)s}. \tag{4c}
\end{align}
Now we solve $(4\text{a})$ and $(4\text{b})$ for $s$ and $y_0$ in order to express them as functions of $x$ and $y$. The result is
$$
y_0=\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^2, \qquad
s=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}. \tag{5}
$$
Plugging $(5)$ into $(4\text{c})$ we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{\phi\!\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^2\right)}
{1-(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})\,\phi\!\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^2\right)}. \tag{6}
$$